# running RabbitMq in CMD

Tags: eclipse, cmd, rabbitmq, java

I'm currently doing the tutorials that can be found on the rabbitMQ webiste and I've run into problems when running the programs in command prompt (Windows7).

Now I have the client libraries working perfectly in Eclipse i.e. I'm able to send messages between a producer and consumer etc. But if I try to run this program in command prompt I get this:

```
Worker.java:1: error: package com.rabbitmq.client does not exist
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
                      ^
Worker.java:2: error: package com.rabbitmq.client does not exist
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
                      ^
Worker.java:3: error: package com.rabbitmq.client does not exist
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
                      ^
etc...... etc..... (this list goes on)....
```

**Now I have added the necessary library (.jar files) locations to the classpath!** and compiling in the command prompt using:

```
javac -cp rabbitmq-client.jar Worker.java
```

but i'm still getting these issues. If anyone can help I would be most grateful.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when trying to get RabbitMQ's sample rabbitmq-java-client running (Netbeans on a linux machine). Even though the code in Netbeans said the packages were there, running mnv install or javac would produce tons of errors like:

> Send.java:11: error: package com.rabbitmq.client does not exist import
>   com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;

I solved it fixing the structure of the directories. They should look like this:

```
my-app
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   `-- java
    |       `-- com
    |           `-- mycompany
    |               `-- app
    |                   `-- App.java
    `-- test
        `-- java
            `-- com
                `-- mycompany
                    `-- app
                        `-- AppTest.java
```

Please see: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_make_my_first_Maven_project

I think that matches what Maven is looking for.

Also, I rebuilt the pom by hand. The pom in the sample rabbitmq-java-client lacks all this information:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
```

It just has

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

See:
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/blob/master/pom.xml

---

Actually, I'm wondering why the poster is doing this in Eclipse.

Now I'm guessing here, but his Worker.java does not need to be edited in an IED. I wonder if we both made the same mistake.

They don't need to be. Just put them in their own directory with these files

```
commons-cli-1.1.jar
commons-io-1.2.jar
rabbitmq-client.jar
```

Then

```
javac -cp rabbitmq-client.jar Worker.java
```

Open RabbitMQ server (`http://localhost:15672/`) then

```
java -cp .:commons-io-1.2.jar:commons-cli-1.1.jar:rabbitmq-client.jar Send
```

next

```
java -cp .:commons-io-1.2.jar:commons-cli-1.1.jar:rabbitmq-client.jar Recv
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html

> The Java client library
>
> RabbitMQ speaks AMQP, which is an open, general-purpose protocol for
>   messaging. There are a number of clients for AMQP in many different
>   languages. We'll use the Java client provided by RabbitMQ.
>
> Download the client library package, and check its signature as
>   described. Unzip it into your working directory and grab the JAR files
>   from the unzipped directory:
>
> $ unzip rabbitmq-java-client-bin-*.zip $ cp
>   rabbitmq-java-client-bin-*/*.jar ./ (The RabbitMQ Java client is also
>   in the central Maven repository, with the groupId com.rabbitmq and the
>   artifactId amqp-client.)

More details and download the Java client library here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html